# Exponential of matrix, taylor series

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Compute $ exp(X) $for $X=$\begin{bmatrix}t&0\\0&s\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}0&t\\-t&0\end{bmatrix} $ and $\begin{bmatrix}0&t\\t&0\end{bmatrix}

The first part of the question I calculated the Taylor series at 0 of $sinh(t), cosh(t), sin(t)$ and $cos(t)$ at $t=0$ so I think I may need to use some of this information for the question. For example I know that $exp(x)=sinh(x)+cosh(x)$

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Have you computed the first several terms of the series for $\exp X$ for each of these?

Comment: I was not sure how to take the exponential of a matrix. Would this just be the exponential of the terms? @Travis

Comment: No, definitely not; what definition of $\exp X$ are you using then?

Comment: @Travis I am not sure. Maybe It is best to calculate it by taylor series. Is this possible for mattrices. I.e writimg taylor exoansion for exponential of x and putting the matrices as x

Comment: That is the usual definition anyway. What is the source of this problem then?

Comment: @Travis is a question from the field of Representation Theory, on Lie Algebras

Comment: @thinker Replace the first matrix by $X$ in the definition of matrix exponential. Can you simplify anything? For instance what is $\begin{bmatrix}t&0\\0&s\end{bmatrix}$ for any given natural number $n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the first matrix you are dealing with is diagonal, it would be easier to use the formula $exp(X) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{X^n}{n!}$

The diagonal entries will be to the power of n in this sum. Hope this helps.